# Extract numbers/characters from string in R and save as variable

Tags: r

I'm quite new to R and I would like to know how I could extract the distance and type out of this type of string: "Just completed a 0.56 mi walk with @RunKeeper". So I would like to store "0.56", "mi" and "walk" into three separate variables. How should I do this?

Thx!
Jeroen.

I tried this:

```
can.be <- function(object, class="numeric") 
  suppressWarnings(!is.na(as(object, class)))

str.vec <- c(text)

str.vec <- strsplit(str.vec, " ")
```

Error in strsplit(str.vec, " ") : non-character argument

```
pos <- sapply(str.vec, function(x) which(sapply(x, can.be)))
[[1]]
```

0.56 
   4

[[2]]
named integer(0)

...
    mapply(`[[`, str.vec, pos)
    mapply(`[[`, str.vec, pos+1)
    mapply(`[[`, str.vec, pos+2)

But now I get this error:

```
> mapply(`[[`, str.vec, pos)
Error in .Primitive("[[")(dots[[1L]][[2L]], dots[[2L]][[2L]]) : 
  attempt to select less than one element
> mapply(`[[`, str.vec, pos+1)
Error in pos + 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
> mapply(`[[`, str.vec, pos+2)
Error in pos + 2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Sample data (text):

```
Just completed a 0.56 mi walk with @RunKeeper. Check it out! http://t.co/lCyzzFeSwq #RunKeeper
Just completed a run in 0:00  with @RunKeeper. Check it out! http://t.co/dJB9DBwF4o #RunKeeper
Just completed a 1.83 km run with @RunKeeper. Check it out! http://t.co/f0S2aKnWXz #RunKeeper
Just completed a 6.03 km run - Gettin' it done! http://t.co/uQ7rBn6M #RunKeeper
Just completed a 1.81 mi walk with @RunKeeper. Check it out! http://t.co/R70fvkLDES #RunKeeper
```

Comment: With these types of questions it always helps to have more than one example and explain why you want to extract the things you want to extract.  For example in this case did you want those three strings because they're the 4th,5th,6th words? Probably not - but with only a single example and without explaining the logic and how you would identify the things you want it's hard to generalize to a solution that actually helps you.

Comment: can you edit again and show (no more than two items of) the list created by `strsplit` and `sapply(...`, thanks. Also, why do you need `c(test)` ?

Comment: Done, what do you mean c(test)? c(text) probably? I changed that from str <- strsplit("Just completed a 0.56 mi walk with @RunKeeper", " ")[[1]]. Replaced "just completed..." with the vector name

Answer (score 2):

if they are expected to be in that particular order then

```
can.be <- function(object, class="numeric") 
  suppressWarnings(!is.na(as(object, class)))

str <- strsplit("Just completed a 0.56 mi walk with @RunKeeper", " ")[[1]]

pos <- which(sapply(str, can.be))

> str[pos]
[1] "0.56"
> str[pos+1]
[1] "mi"
> str[pos+2]
[1] "walk"
```

it needs the sequence to be always the same. **But** you can hard code a series of unit of measurements (like `mi`, `km`, etc) to identify them into the sequence (even though is more then likely that you always have *number* and then *mi*. Provided that there are no other numbers into the string, this method should be quite robust.

EDIT:

for a vector:

```
str.vec <- c("Just completed a 0.56 mi walk with @RunKeeper", "Just completed a 13 mi cycling with @Michele")

str.vec <- strsplit(str.vec, " ")

pos <- sapply(str.vec, function(x) which(sapply(x, can.be)))

> mapply(`[[`, str.vec, pos)
[1] "0.56" "13"  
> mapply(`[[`, str.vec, pos+1)
[1] "mi" "mi"
> mapply(`[[`, str.vec, pos+2)
[1] "walk"    "cycling"
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I get this working for the rest of my data? It only seems to work for the first case.

Comment: @user2523290 of course, just edit our question with part of your data (or a similar version of it)

Comment: Ok, got it. That would mean looping it through all cases then

Comment: @user2523290 one sort of loop (implicit or explicit) will be definitely needed. However this does not necessarily mean that you'll need an explicit `for` loop. for example, `strsplit` is vectorised, which means that, if you have all the strings in one character vector, all of them will be split in one run (and very fast). Then `which(sapply(str, can.be))` will most probably be wrapped into another `sapply` to run through each list item

Comment: Something like this then? can.be <- function(object, class="numeric") 
suppressWarnings(!is.na(as(object, class)))
str <- strsplit (text, " ")
pos <- sapply(which(sapply(str, can.be)text)
distance = str[pos]
unit = str[pos+1]
sport = str[pos+2]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the edit. I think it’s close now, but I still get some error. I tried to replace the text for str.vec with the vector itself (text):

> str.vec <- c(text)
> str.vec
But now I get this error: 
> mapply(`[[`, str.vec, pos)
Error in .Primitive("[[")(dots[[1L]][[2L]], dots[[2L]][[2L]]) : 
  attempt to select less than one element
> mapply(`[[`, str.vec, pos+1)
Error in pos + 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
> mapply(`[[`, str.vec, pos+2)
Error in pos + 2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: @user2523290 you can edit your question adding a reproducible example, and so show step by step where you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

If the string has always the same format, you can use :

```
dist<-as.numeric(substr(text,18,21))
unit<-substr(text,22,23)
way<-substr(text,25,28)
```

But it won't work if it doesn't, for example if the number's length change (from 0.56 to 12.21 for example). You must make sure it doesn't happend !

Comment: Well then I think you can't make what you want in R. Maybe you should treat your strings in another language like C++ and the import your datas in R ?

Comment: Or if it's just the number's length which changes, you may be able to fix it writing "0...0." instead of "0.", with as many "0" as necessary given your dataset.

Comment: @Vincent - It's always possible that another language *might* make a certain task easier... however, your first assumption should never be that R _can't_ do something.  That's a horrible attitude and you will rarely be correct.

Comment: Well I'm sure R can't do anything. R is designed to answer to statistical questions, its purpose is not to do anything even if you can do much with loops and if statements. So here I must admit I was wrong but it's not "horrible" to advise someone doing a task in a more appropriate language than the one he was intending to use. Up to him to decide wether he follow the advice or not.

Comment: I guess my point is that if you're truly under the impression that you should switch to a different language to do something as simple as a text manipulation then maybe you should learn more about R before recommending anybody to not use it.

Comment: I won't answer more cause it spoils the topic  but I think you don't get what I say. I didn't say "hey i'm a pro R programmer and there is nothing for you here trust me I can't be wrong". I said "I think you should switch to a more appropriate language". I'm a student, I obviously don't know everything about R. But telling what I know when I see the question and as nobody answered yet might still help. Maybe you should read my answer again and try to understand my point instead of looking down of the poor unpro student I am. ;)

Good night though.